# warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

//no se si se tenga que configurar algo en el php (agregar otra opcion)
//no tengo contraseña

$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root") 
  or die("Problemas en la conexion");

//aqui es el error, pero ya intente voltearlos
//pero me aparece si los volteo problemas en el select

mysqli_select_db("cursos",$conexion)
  or die("Problemas en la seleccion de la base de datos");
//aqui mis base de datos

mysqli_query("insert into cursos(nombre,mail,codigocurso) values 
  ('$_REQUEST[nombre]','$_REQUEST[mail]','$_REQUEST[codigocurso]')", 
   $conexion) or die("Problemas en el select".mysqli_error());

mysqli_close($conexion);

echo "El alumno fue dado de alta.";
?>
```

Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectofinal\insertar2.php on line 10
 Problemas en la seleccion de la base de datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta línea de código la tienes con los valores invertidos:

```
mysqli_select_db("cursos",$conexion)
```

Debe ser primero la conexión y luego la base de datos  elegida

```
mysqli_select_db($conexion, "cursos")
```

Comment: Ya lo hice pero, me dice que tengo error en :                     
   mysqli_query("insert into cursos(nombre,mail,codigocurso) values 
   ('$_REQUEST[nombre]','$_REQUEST[mail]','$_REQUEST[codigocurso]')", 
   $conexion) or die("Problemas en el select".mysqli_error());

Comment: @scrib scribd y que error te aparece?

Comment: Estoy suponiendo que estás en XAMP y si se supone que tu base de datos no tiene contraseña de igual debes colocar asi $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "")

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectofinal\insertar2.php on line 14
Notice: Undefined index: mail in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectofinal\insertar2.php on line 14
Notice: Undefined index: codigocurso in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectofinal\insertar2.php on line 14
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectofinal\insertar2.php on line 15
Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectofinal\insertar2.php on line 15
 Problemas en el select

Answer (score 1):

Inténtalo de esta manera, es más sencillo!

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa esta mejor :)
Primero el host en este caso localhost, luego el usuario, contraseña y por ultimo la base de datos.

```html
 $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "contraseña", "base_de_datos");
 if(!$conexion){
 echo "No se puede conectar a la base de datos";
 }
```