# ¿como soluciono este error en mi código php?

Tags: php, mysql

hola que tal estaba intentando hacer un registro con una base de datos de mysql
pero a la hora ejecutarlo me aparece un error que no me deja avanzar

> "Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lol\regis.php on line 3"

ya he visto videos y la verdad no me han servido de mucho por aqui les dejo el codigo gracias

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>registro</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="regis.php" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><laber>Nombre completo</laber></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre usuario"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><laber>contraseña</laber></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="contraseña" placeholder="contraseña"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><laber>email</laber></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                    <td><label><input type="submit" value="Registrarme"></input></label></td>
                    <td><label><input type="reset" value="Reestablecer"></input></label></td>
        </tr>


    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

parte de php

```
<?php
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
  $db = mysqli_select_db($link,"lincon") or die ("<h2>Error de Conexion</h2>");

  if(isset($_POST['nombre'])) {
     $nombre =$_POST['nombre'];
     $contraseña =$_POST['contraseña'];
     $email =$_POST['email'];
  }

  $req = (strlen($nombre)*strlen($contraseña)*strlen($email));

  mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO datos VALUES ('','$nombre','$contraseña','$email')")


?>
```

me seria de mucha ayuda si me ayudaran a identificar el error se supone que error esta en esta parte del codigo

```
$db = mysqli_select_db("lincon",$link) or die ("<h2>Error de Conexion</h2>");
```

postdata "lincon es la base de datos "

Comment: OHH Gracias pero ahora me aparece un error en la linea 11

Comment: este es el error que me aparece "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lol\regis.php on line 11" y esta es la linea del codigo  "mysqli_query("INSERT INTO datos VALUES ('','$nombre','$contraseña','$email')",$link)
"

Comment: Posible duplicado de [warning: mysqli\_select\_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/269034/warning-mysqli-select-db-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los problemas son dos, el primero es porque tienes los parámetros al revés, primero va la conexión y luego la base de datos y el otro error se debe a la razon de que en php tienes que comprobrar primero si es que una variable existe para que pueda leer tu codigo y el resto de tus variables, eso se hace de la siguiente forma.

```
<?php
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
  $db = mysqli_select_db($link, "lincon") or die ("<h2>Error de Conexion</h2>");

  if(isset($_POST['nombre'])) {
     $nombre =$_POST['nombre'];
     $contraseña =$_POST['contraseña'];
     $email =$_POST['email'];
  }

  $req = (strlen($nombre)*strlen($contraseña)*strlen($email));

  $insertar = "INSERT INTO datos (id (si es autonumerico no es necesario colocarlo), nombre, contraseña, email) VALUES ('$nombre', '$contraseña', $email')";
  mysqli_real_query($link, $insertar);


?>
```

Agregando el isset es como obtendrias que te lea todas esas variables declaradas y php pasaria a ponerlas en tu BD.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100274/discussion-on-answer-by-asasced-como-soluciono-este-error-en-mi-codigo-php).