# mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given

Tags: php, html, ajax, mysqli, phpmyadmin

conexion exitosa
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PolleriaVickys_v9\ajax\procesar.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: IdContacto in C:\xampp\htdocs\PolleriaVickys_v9\ajax\procesar.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: FechaCrea in C:\xampp\htdocs\PolleriaVickys_v9\ajax\procesar.php on line 11
Se ha recibido el mensaje Carla[image: no me muestra los datos registrados en el admin pero si registra en la base de datos]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [warning: mysqli\_select\_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/269034/warning-mysqli-select-db-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli)

Comment: `mysqli_select_db` tiene que que tener la conexion, no el localhost